# Xaml textbox backspace/arrow keys dosent work

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox

I got a application, and In this application I am opening a new XAML window where I got a Textbox, 
In this textbox I can write, but not use delete, backspace or arrow keys.

If I do, the marker is still in the main application. 
I cant see to find anything when googling, and it's ordinary marcup.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtFileName, Path=Text}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtFileName"/>
```

And the C# code to opening up (this code exsists inside a button click event)

```
var window = new XamlWindow();
window.Show();
```

When I capture the OnKeyDown event, it is beeing triggerd, on all key's except for backspace, delete and arrowkeys.
What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" />
```

Output after pressing 'D', Left Arrow, Backspace, Delete

```
preview keydown -->D<--
preview keydown -->Left<--
preview keydown -->Back<--
preview keydown -->Delete<--
```

Comment: yes it does. that is output from my sample app. if you are still having trouble i will provide the whole thing